# The Computer freezes or reboot after installing an off board graphics card

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, freeze, reboot

I have a server motherboard (Supermicro X9dri-f). The problem is when I install an off board (external graphics card) to one of the PCI-E x16, the computer boots to windows desktop but after 3-4mins the computer freezes or reboot by itself.

This is not the case using the oneboard video. I have tested 2 graphics cards, one of them is geforce gtx 970. The two gpus result in the same problem.

Note that all the external power cables are connected from a decent 1200W power supply.

System specifications:
Motherboard: supermicro X9DRi-F
Ram: hp DDR3 ECC 1333 (4gb x 4)
Cpu: dual E5-2630 v0 
Psu: 1200w hp redundant 
Os: Windows server 2012
————-
P.s The system is very stable, once the gpu is attached it keeps crashing. I have tested all 3 pCI-E slots.

I appreciate your reply,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Flash latest bios for the X9Dr-f AND BE CAREFUL, follow ALL the Bios flash instructions (at the end don't forget to remove battery and reset CMOS)
2. Load bios defaults
3. Insert video card
4. In the bios Change PCI-E Gen3 to Gen1 and x16
5. Video priority change to Offboard
6. PCI-E addressing to Above 4G
7. ASPM set to auto
8. Move Onboard VGA jumper  on the motherboard to off-board position.

hope this helps. Your milage will vary... It's a server board, they usually don't support much in the way of gpu's.

Comment: Thank you, The only thing I did after swithching to offboard video in BIOS is moving the jumper to offboard or (disabled onboard) vga position. It works and very stable.

Comment: Very nice. Glad it works.